# PHP date function showing wrong week

Tags: php, date

Why is PHP date("W") showing that the current week is 2? Shouldn't it be on week 3?

In the PHP documentation it says: weeks starting on Monday. Does that mean it just ignored the  first 3 days of this year?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, [week 2](http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/weeknumbers.php) is correct.

> Week number according to the [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)
>   standard, weeks starting on Monday.
>   The first week of the year is the week
>   that contains that year's first
>   Thursday. The highest week number in a
>   year is either 52 or 53.

Comment: this is also why the ISO year for 10-1-1 was 2009

Answer (score 1):

2010-01-01 - 2010-01-03 are days in the 53th week that started on 2009-12-28.

edit: example script

```
$ts = strtotime('2009-12-27');
$end = strtotime('2010-01-26');

for($ts=strtotime('2009-12-27'); $ts<strtotime('2010-01-07'); $ts=strtotime('+1 day', $ts)) {
  echo date('Y-m-d W', $ts), "\n";
}
```

prints

```
2009-12-27 52
2009-12-28 53
2009-12-29 53
2009-12-30 53
2009-12-31 53
2010-01-01 53
2010-01-02 53
2010-01-03 53
2010-01-04 01
2010-01-05 01
2010-01-06 01
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this means that the first three days of the year belong to the 52nd week of last year.